# Need help with identifying the font of "abc" in the shown logo

Tags: fonts, font-identification

I need help with identifying the font of "abc" in the "abc web consulting" logo. I am guessing it's [Brandish](http://www.fonts2u.com/brandish-regular.font) but the "c" and the thickness of Brandish does not match the one in the logo.

[image]

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally tend to think, in cases where the letters are so simple and geometric, that they are done by hand.

Doing the letters of your logo or acronym by hand gives you extra flexibility and infinite possibilities to get a result exactly to your liking.

It *is* normal for someone to start their design based on a font, but I find it hard to believe a professional designer will deliver a typeface logo with the use of a font "as is".

Play with the kerning, the bézier curve or line thickness, but **not** for the sake of it. Do it to get exactly what you had in mind during your drafting and brainstorming sessions, rather than settling for what the font gives you.

Comment: Thanks! I just got a message from my client as well. He said this logo font was modified. I thought there was a font for it cause it kinda looks like Brandish. Thanks for you answer!